# how to run one scenario from another Scenario in Specrun

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, specflow, specrun

I have a 2 scenarios .

```
@Joinnow
Scenario Outline: join as a user


@changePasswrd
Scenario Outline: Change Password
```

Now i want to run @Joinnow as a part of @change password initial step. How would i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

to do this you can create a new step which calls all of the other steps in the other scenario. The [specflow wiki has some details of how to do this](https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Calling-Steps-from-Step-Definitions) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5228030/specflow-re-usable-step-definitions) also gives similar information

Comment: well i know i can share the steps but how about running whole @join now scenario with all of its parameter without sharing the steps ?

Comment: You can't just 'call' the other scenario. You could copy the whole thing to s background in another feature, but it can't be a scenario outline then

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to think about a background. Why do you want to use the other scenario with this scenario? Do they share similar steps? Do you need it in a certain state? Or is it just to select the right user login? A background works well for using a particular user.

Cucumber link but it works the same in specflow
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Background

There is also setup with a tag, which will run before a scenario if you want. 
https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Hooks